# DB2 Toad SQL - Group by Certain Columns using Max Command

Tags: sql, group-by, db2, toad

I am having some trouble with the below query. I do understand I need to group by ID and Category, but I only want to group by ID while keeping the rest of the columns based on Rank being max. Is there a way to only group by certain columns?

```
select ID, Category, max(rank)
from schema.table1
group by ID
```

Input:

```
ID   Category   Rank
111  3          4
111  1          5
123  5          3
124  7          2
```

Current Output

```
ID   Category   Rank
111  3          4
111  9          1
123  5          3
124  7          2
```

Desired Output

```
ID   Category   Rank
111  1          5
123  5          3
124  7          2
```

Comment: Shouldn't the first line of the desired output be (111, 1, 5)?

Comment: You are exactly correct! I will edit the post. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
select *
from table1
where (id, rank) in (select id, max(rank) from table1 group by id)
```

Result:

```
ID   CATEGORY  RANK 
---- --------- ---- 
111  1         5    
123  5         3    
124  7         2
```

Or you can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` window function. For example:

```
select * 
from (
  select *,
    row_number() over(partition by id order by rank desc) as rn
  from table1
) x
where rn = 1
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=c5c7af24693b407c55f9873cfbbf0c65).

Answer (score 1):

You can try using - `row_number()`

```
select * from
(
select ID, Category,rank, row_number() over(partition by id order by rank desc) as rn
from schema.table1
)A where rn=1
```